# GIF term animation in gnuplot with multiplot

Tags: animation, gnuplot, gif

I came across the gif terminal in gnuplot. I read that it keeps track of each plot command until the second `set out` command is encountered.
Recently, the need for an animated multiplot came up - is there any way of achieving this with the gif terminal?
What I need essentially is a matrix of three plots, each one animated, in some grid I can specify.

Comment: what is your attempt? there are indeed a lot of examples around: http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.fr/2011/09/creating-gif-animation-using-gnuplot.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a normal single plot environment each `plot` command creates a new frame. In a multiplot environment each `set multiplot` - `unset multiplot` pair creates a new frame which can contain several `plot` commands like this example:

```
set terminal gif animate delay 100
set output "multiplot_animated.gif"

n = 50
dphi = 2*pi/n

do for [i=0:(n-1)] {
   phi = i*dphi
   set multiplot layout 2,1
      plot sin(x+phi)
      plot cos(x+phi)
   unset multiplot
}
```

This is the result. Skip the `delay 100` (or change the number) to change the animation speed.

[image: animated multiplot]

Comment: I kept putting the for loop within the set and unset multiplot! Thanks for this!